# Yandex Map Kit удаление значка "Я"

Tags: java, android, яндекс-карты, yandexmapkit

Использую в своем приложении yandex map kit. Если работает GPS, то на карте появляется значок "Я", который, я так полагаю, перемещается в зависимости от спутника, вместе с ним и перемещается карта. Вариант с блокировкой карты, не подходит. Поэтому мне необходимо убрать значок "Я" с карты. Как это сделать? [image]

Answer (score 1):

Если это MapKit 3.0, то нужно выключить/не включать User Location Layer.